# Qt: How to get the response from a GET?

Tags: qt, get, request, response, signals-slots

I'm having trouble collecting the response from a web request i do. (Because i'm new to Qt).

Why do i have trouble?

I have a request class which send a request and receive a response. But i can't get the response to the parent of the request object, because i have to wait for a "finished" signal from the NetworkAccessMaanager which handles the response.

So i handle the response in a "finished" slot, but i can't return the info to the parent main window holding the request object. How can i do this?

Here's the code:

**Main window.cpp:**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_buttonLogin_clicked()
{
    request->sendRequest("www.request.com");
}
```

**Request.cpp:**

```
Request::Request()
{
  oNetworkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
  QObject::connect(oNetworkAccessManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
}

/*
 * Sends a request
 */
QNetworkReply* Request::sendRequest(QString url)
{
    QUrl httpRequest(url);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setSslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration()); // Set default ssl config
    request.setUrl(httpRequest); // Set the url
    QNetworkReply *reply = oNetworkAccessManager->get(QNetworkRequest(httpRequest));

    return reply;
}

/*
 * Runs when the request is finished and has received a response
 */
void Request::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
       // Reading attributes of the reply
       // e.g. the HTTP status code
       QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
       // Or the target URL if it was a redirect:
       QVariant redirectionTargetUrl =
       reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
       // see CS001432 on how to handle this

       // no error received?
       if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
       {
           // Reading the data from the response
           QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();
           QString jsonString(bytes); // string

           bool ok;
           QVariantMap jsonResult = Json::parse(jsonString,ok).toMap();
           if(!ok)
           {
               qFatal("An error occured during parsing");
               exit(1);
           }


           // Set the jsonResult
           setJsonResult(jsonResult);


       }
       // Some http error received
       else
       {
           // handle errors here
       }

       // We receive ownership of the reply object
       // and therefore need to handle deletion.
       delete reply;
}

/*
 * Set the json result so that other functions can get it
 */
void Request::setJsonResult(QVariantMap jsonResult)
{
    m_jsonResult = jsonResult;
}

/*
 * Get the json result
 * Return null if there is no result
 */
QVariantMap Request::getJsonResult()
{
    return m_jsonResult;
}
```

Any ideas of how i can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, this is old, very old, but I saw something that I think is worth mentioning: we should't delete the reply in the finish slot, as the doc says: "Note: After the request has finished, it is the responsibility of the user to delete the QNetworkReply object at an appropriate time. Do not directly delete it inside the slot connected to finished(). You can use the deleteLater() function."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each `QNetworkReply` emits `finished()` signal, so you should connect signal from  `QNetworkReply*` returned by `request->sendRequest("www.request.com");` to slot of `MainWindow`.

EXAMPLE:

```
void MainWindow::on_buttonLogin_clicked()
{
    QNetworkReply *reply = request->sendRequest("www.request.com");
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(newslot()));
}

void MainWindow::newslot()
{
    QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
    // there you can handle reply as you wish
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the QNetworkReply that emits finsished()? It looks like it's the NetworkAccssManager that does this.

Comment: i have intentionally made a mistaken request. i am trying to get the response body of the erroneous reply. I have successfully extracted the error code (401) that is unauthorized access. but when i try to get the body of the reply using reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString(), gives me empty string. but if i use     QByteArray bts = reply->readAll();, it gives me the error message when convert it to string, but why the first method is not working?